# How to change the path for which java

Tags: 14.04

Now I am working in React Native,I tired to run my app it shows an error.

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

See the below pic.

[image: I already set path for my java]

I already set path for my java,see the second pic.If i put this command `which java` it shows `/usr/bin/java`.But If i put this command `echo $JAVA_HOME` it shows `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin`

I want to set the two path must be same.Please help me to solve this error.
[image: See this pic]

Comment: It is best to copy paste the text directly to the question, instead of a screenshot, because that way it is easier to read, to copy paste, and for search engines to find the question for future readers with the same problem. Screenshots containing text are almost always strongly discouraged throughout stack exchange. To make the text maintain its formatting add four spaces before each line so it is considered code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

to

```
PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
```

and reopen the terminal